# Optimization with many queries in page

Tags: php, html, mysql, optimization, mysqli

I have in my page 5 queries that im wishing to have just one query if its possible , i dont know if there is a better strategy to what im doing or its ok .

this is my main query to load the books

```
 $mess = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * from ( SELECT m.id, cm.voteup,
                                                  cm.votedown,cr.book_descr FROM books m
                           INNER JOIN  books_vote cm ON cm.bookid = m.id
                           INNER JOIN  book_info cr ON cr.bookid = m.id
                           WHERE bookid = ?  ORDER BY m.date DESC LIMIT 30)ddd 
                           ORDER BY m.date ASC');
    $mess->bind_param("i", $book);                              
    $mess->execute();
    $mess->store_result();
    $mess->bind_result($id,$voteup,$votedown);
        while($row = $mess->fetch()){
             //  im fetching here in this <div class='areabooks'>  
              }
```

> Then i reset the query to fetch  in other div with IF condition

```
  $mess->data_seek(0);
  while($row = $mess->fetch()){
    if($voteup - $votedown >= 5){
      //I fetch here in this <div class='areabooks2'>
        }
        }
```

> Then im cheking the top `MAX(voteup - votedown )` with this query

```
 $messtop = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ..........
                           INNER JOIN ...
                           INNER JOIN ( select id ,MAX(voteup - votedown ) as maxe
                                from books
                                where voteup - votedown >= 5
                                group by id  ) tt
                           WHERE bookid = ?
                           ORDER BY maxe DESC,cm.votedown asc,cm.voteup DESC
                           limit 1');
    $messtop->bind_param("i", $book);                              
    $messtop->execute();
    $messtop->store_result();
    $messtop->bind_result($id,$voteup,$votedown);
    $messtop->fetch();
    // then i fetch in this <div class='topbook' >
```

> Then i reset the first query again to fetch in other div with IF condition

```
$mess->data_seek(0); 
while($row = $mess->fetch()){
    if($votedown - $voteup >= 5){
       //I fetch here in this <div class='areabooks3' >
    }
}
```

> Then im getting the top `MAX(votedown - voteup )` with this query

```
   $messtop = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ..........
                           INNER JOIN ...
                           INNER JOIN ( select id ,MAX(votedown - voteup) as maxe
                                from books where votedown - voteup >= 5
                                group by id  ) tt
                           WHERE bookid = ?
                           ORDER BY maxe DESC,cm.voteup ASC,cm.votedown DESC
                           limit 1');
    $messdown->bind_param("i", $book);                              
    $messdown->execute();
    $messdown->store_result();
    $messdown->bind_result($id,$voteup,$votedown);
    $messdown->fetch();
    // then i fetch in this <div class='topbottonbook' >
```

What im looking for is if there is a strategy to use just one query and fetch it in all these divs , those divs are separated  like that .

```
 <first div>
 <second div>
 <3rd div>
 <4th div>
  5th div
```

How to simplify this thanks ?

Comment: Unclear.  You have "bookid" without an alias and "book_id" with an alias.  Are they the same?  Please have aliases on all columns.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- need to see indexes, etc.

Comment: @RickJames sorry , yes they are same . have no indexes

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if the 3 queries can be combined into one.

First query:

Postpone the `JOIN` until you have the 30 'latest' `bookids`.  That is, move the JOINs out to the outer `SELECT`.

Also have `INDEX(id, date)`.  But I am confused.  Ordinarily `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, hence unique.  Yet the query implies that one book has multiple dates.  What gives?  (*Please* provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

The mysql commandline tool (or Workbench or phpmyadmin) is your friend.  Manually run the queries using one of them.  I think that you will find errors.  Please fix.